# Отправка APDU на UICC Android 7.0

Tags: android

Как отправить APDU команду на UICC карту. Карта не SIM, с собственным ПО и командами. При помещении карты в телефон карта не обнаруживается. SEEK for Android и TelephonyManager не помогают, из-за того, что UICC не обнаружена телефоном. Возможно стоит попробовать RILD Socket ?

Comment: Наверное я стремительно старею - половину слов не понимаю ну и тем более вопрос мне тоже непонятен :)

Answer (score 0):

Телефон, при подключении sim карты шлет на нее apdu команды, опрашивая файловую систему и проверя наличие определенных файлов. Т.е. необходмо реализовать на sim карте файловую систему. Смотри ETSI TS 151 001.
После этого функция iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel будет рабочей. При условии что приложение системное ( перенесено в каталог /system/priv-app/наименование_приложения.) или имеются carier права.